# Param as router - ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I have routes like `:id/comments/`, `:id/otherRoute` etc.
For these routes I need to create new controller.
For example:

```
let id: number = +req.params["id"];
new controller(id).getComments().then(comments => {
    res.json(response("error", {comments: comments}))
}).catch((error) => {
    res.json(response("error", {error: error}))
})
```

Is there any way to use new router for routes `:id/` and create `controller` globally for all routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to make a middleware so you can do the llogic for all the routes that have the :id param, for example:

```
app.use('/something/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    //some code logic
    //error handling
    if(error){ next(error); }
    else { next(); }
});
```

There's also the possibility of using the param middleware in witch you can do stuff with the param:

```
app.param('id', (req, res, next, id) => {
    somefunction()
    .then(() => {
        //some logic with param.id
        next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        next(error);
    });
});
```

You can see more about middlewares in this link: [express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can pass variable from middleware to route ? I was trying to pass it as parameter of `next()`, but I don't know how to access it from route.

Comment: The next callback is only to pass an error to the error handling middleware if its like this next(error), or to pass to the next middleware if it is like this: next(). You can not put back a variable to the route, you just have to operate with the req.param.id . this way you will have the changes when you pick it up in the final controller. The object req is persistent.